# Can I use "box-sizing: border-box;" in universal selector (*) every time?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I just learned html css and currently I'm trying to improve my skills by practicing. Everytime I open a new html page I'm using `*{box sizing: border-box;}`. Is it okay to use it like this every time or should I use it in the codes that I need?

Comment: That completely depends on one to one code implementation some uses and some don't. technically there is no restriction on use the `box-sizing` on the `(*)` selector which basically better than setting on individual elements.

Comment: This is a great question and should be reopened IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start a new project it might be ok and clean to add `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` at the beginning so you can use it on the entire project and everyone else developing on the project will see it.

**BUT** if you work on an existing project and then just add `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` somewhere could mess up the entire layout! So there it might be "safer" to only add it to the containers you are working on with something like `.border-boxed-container * { box-sizing: border-box; }`. Or have an extra class like `"border-boxed"` which you can add to every element accordingly the CSS `.border-boxed { box-sizing: border-box; }`

Answer (score 3):

It’s not a right or wrong sort of thing. Depending on the situation, there’s good reasons for using either border-box or content-box.
When creating something that needs precision in terms of size relative to others on the same row (e.g. a grid system that needs to total 100% per row), using border-box will simplify things and reduce surprises.
But if you need precision with the sizing of an element relative to its interior (ex. a perfect fit around a fixed-size image), content-box makes more sense.